# Multiple Values to Trigger #states

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

How can I have multiple values trigger the Form API's #states?

Say for example, I wanted this field to be visible not only if the value is 5 (currently works below), but wanted to make the field visible if the the values are 3, 4 or 5.

```
'#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
       ':input[name="field_star_rating"]' => array('value' => t('5')),
    ),
),
```

As a note, I tried the following and it **does not work**.  It only works if the value is '4'

```
'#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_star_rating"]' => array('value' => t('5')),
        ':input[name="field_star_rating"]' => array('value' => t('4')),
    ),
),
```

This also **does not work**, it too only works if the value is '4':

```
'#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_star_rating"]' => array('value' => t('5'), 'value' => t('4')),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
'#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_star_rating"]' => array(
            array('value' => t('5')),
            array('value' => t('4'))
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct way, the current one marked as correct is wrong. See this issue for more info:
http://drupal.org/node/735528

Comment: The #states API sure has come a long way sense 2011. Marking as correct.

Comment: this is a great answer, and I came here from Google, like a dozen times... a bounty is on its way.

Comment: It is working fine for normal view. After running any 'ajax', it added again and again

Comment: In my case with hook_form_alter of an existing node form the states only changed correctly when i added [und] to the name: input[name="field_star_rating[und]"]' => array(

Answer (score 3):

Only way I could figure is to use #ajax in D7.

Here are a few helpful tip's I wish I would have known before starting.

1. #ajax in the form API is awesome and worth learning
2. #states does not support OR or XOR (Without a patch? http://drupal.org/node/735528 )
3. dpm($form); and var_dump($form_state) on a custom submit function are priceless

Here is a modified version of one of the AJAX examples from the examples module.

```
function plugin_autotextfields($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['star_rating'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Star Rating'),
        '#options' => array('_none' => '- select -', 5 => '5 Star', 4 => '4 Star', 3 => '3 Star', 2 => '2 Star', 1 => '1 Star'),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'plugin_autotextfields_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'textfields',
            'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
    );

    $form['textfields'] = array(
        '#title' => t("Fieldset Name"),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="textfields">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#description' => t('Where the field will be placed'),
    );

    if (!empty($form_state['values']['star_rating']) && $form_state['values']['star_rating'] == 5) {
        $form['textfields']['review'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Message if 5 stars'),
        );
    } else if (!empty($form_state['values']['star_rating'])) {
        $form['textfields']['review'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Message if not 5 stars'),
        );
    }

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Click Me'),
    );

    return $form;
}

function omfg_autotextfields_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['textfields'];
}
```

I hope this helps someone that runs into the same problem :)

Comment: Wow! Very helpful answer my friend. I have been wrapping my head around an issue with #states and now have it working but #ajax would of obviously been easier now that you slapped me with a clue-stick. And that debugging tip as a bonus? Sorry I have to pay you with measly karma. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
 $form['student_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array(
      'high_school'   => t('High School'),
      'undergraduate' => t('Undergraduate'),
      'graduate'      => t('Graduate'),
    ),
    '#title' => t('What type of student are you?')
  );

// High school information.
  $form['high_school']['tests_taken'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('What standardized tests did you take?'),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(   // action to take.
        ':input[name="student_type[high_school]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ':input[name="student_type[undergraduate]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ':input[name="student_type[graduate]"]' => array('checked' => FALSE),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

P.S. See the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) for more features  "form_example/form_example_states.inc"